# Symfony security / access_control, lots of redundant entries

Tags: php, symfony, security

`security.yml` has `access_control` entries and each is a combination of:

- a URL pattern
- a host name pattern
- channel requirement (http, https)
- roles requirements

My understanding is Symfony only matches ONE per request, but this is also the highest-level place to enforce HTTPS.

So then, does this mean a duplicate rule for each unique URL pattern / role requirement?

- # rules..
- a rule for /admin requiring ROLE_ADMIN for localhost
- a rule for /admin requiring ROLE_ADMIN, forcing https
- a rule for /api requiring ROLE_API for localhost
- a rule for /api requiring ROLE_API, forcing https
- a rule for / allowing anonymous for localhost
- a rule for / allowing anonymous, forcing https
- # more rules..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, for each incoming request, Symfony will decide which `access_control` to use based on *the URI*, the client's *IP address*, the incoming **"HOST NAME"!**, and the *request method*.

But for your happiness there is a way to not duplicate the rules and achieve the same goal.

---

#### "The Special `parameters.yml` File"

> It defines the values that usually change on each server.

First, in your local development machine, define a new parameter into `app/config/parameters.yml` file, let's named **"requires_channel"**:

```
# in your local development machine (development)
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    # ...
    requires_channel: http  # <- Wow! I can use this var anywhere into my configuration :)
```

make the same in production server, but setting `https`:

```
# in your deployment server (production)
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    # ...
    requires_channel: https # <- I need enforce https redirection now in production server
```

Now, you can to define only one rule per entry and use your new `%requires_channel%` parameter:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: '%requires_channel%' }
        # ...
```

**`%requires_channel%`**: **its value depends to the host where running your application**.

Note that `host` attribute is not important anymore, because it was needed to differentiate both rules before.

---

This solution could be done by using environments config files (`config_dev.yml` and `config_prod.yml`), but probably you need test your application for prod environment too in localhost (http). So the above solution should be enough for you ;)

---

I hope I've helped!

Comment: Wow! It's configs all the way down.